# My if statement is robust. How can I make it more compact?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a robus code that does its job but is rather ugly. The code pick up values from "Data" sheet based on its ItemType and copy it into the appropriate worksheet. Sounds simple. However, there are some aesthetical flaws like the gridlines have been deleted and cell formatting is distorted.
I would appreciate any help or suggestion.

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()

Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
'-----------Mfg FG
Dim rng1 As Range
'-----------Mfg RAW
Dim rng2 As Range
'-----------Mfg Sub-Assy
Dim rng3 As Range
'-----------Resale
Dim rng4 As Range
'-----------Conv Resale
Dim rng5 As Range
'-----------Mfg FG PE
Dim rng6 As Range
'-----------Mfg Sub-Assy PE
Dim rng7 As Range
'-----------Acrylics
Dim rng8 As Range
'-----------Mfg Raw PE
Dim rng9 As Range
'-----------Mfg FG PVC
Dim rng10 As Range
'-----------Mfg Raw PVC
Dim rng11 As Range
'-----------Mfg Sub-Assy PVC
Dim rng12 As Range

'--------------------------------------------------------

Set rng1 = Worksheets("ABCX Mfg FG").Range("A13:C1370")
Set rng2 = Worksheets("ABCX Mfg RAW").Range("A13:C1370")
Set rng3 = Worksheets("ABCX Mfg Sub-Assy").Range("A13:C1370")
Set rng4 = Worksheets("ABCX Resale").Range("A13:C1370")
Set rng5 = Worksheets("ABCX Conv Resale").Range("A13:C1370")
Set rng6 = Worksheets("ABCX Mfg FG PE").Range("A13:C1370")
Set rng7 = Worksheets("ABCX Mfg Sub-Assy PE").Range("A13:C1370")
Set rng8 = Worksheets("ABCX Acrylics").Range("A13:C1370")
Set rng9 = Worksheets("ABCX Mfg Raw PE").Range("A13:C1370")
Set rng10 = Worksheets("ABCX Mfg FG PVC").Range("A13:C1370")
Set rng11 = Worksheets("ABCX Mfg Raw PVC").Range("A13:C1370")
Set rng12 = Worksheets("ABCX Mfg Sub-Assy PVC").Range("A13:C1370")

'---------------------------------------------------------

   With Worksheets("Data")
      LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

      For i = 2 To LastRow

        If .Cells(i, 6) = "Mfg FG" Then
          With Worksheets("ABCX Mfg FG")

            .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = _
               Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 1).Value

            .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1) = _
               Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 8).Value

            .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2) = _
               Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 9).Value

            rng1.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3)

          End With
        End If

        If .Cells(i, 6) = "Mfg RAW" Then
          With Worksheets("ABCX Mfg RAW")

            .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = _
               Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 1).Value

            .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1) = _
               Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 8).Value

            .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2) = _
               Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 9).Value

            rng2.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3)

          End With
        End If

        If .Cells(i, 6) = "Mfg Sub-Assy" Then
          With Worksheets("ABCX Mfg Sub-Assy")

            .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = _
               Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 1).Value

            .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1) = _
               Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 8).Value

            .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2) = _
               Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 9).Value

            rng3.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3)

          End With
        End If

        If .Cells(i, 6) = "Resale" Then
          With Worksheets("ABCX Resale")

            .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = _
               Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 1).Value

            .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1) = _
               Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 8).Value

            .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2) = _
               Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 9).Value

            rng4.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3)

          End With
        End If

        If .Cells(i, 6) = "Conv Resale" Then
          With Worksheets("ABCX Conv Resale")

            .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = _
               Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 1).Value

            .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1) = _
               Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 8).Value

            .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2) = _
               Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 9).Value

            rng5.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3)

          End With
        End If

        If .Cells(i, 6) = "Mfg FG PE" Then
          With Worksheets("ABCX Mfg FG PE")

            .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = _
               Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 1).Value

            .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1) = _
               Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 8).Value

            .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2) = _
               Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 9).Value

            rng6.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3)

          End With
        End If

        If .Cells(i, 6) = "Mfg Sub-Assy PE" Then
          With Worksheets("ABCX Mfg Sub-Assy PE")

            .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = _
               Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 1).Value

            .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1) = _
               Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 8).Value

            .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2) = _
               Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 9).Value

            rng7.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3)

          End With
        End If

        If .Cells(i, 6) = "Acrylics" Then
          With Worksheets("ABCX Acrylics")

            .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = _
               Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 1).Value

            .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1) = _
               Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 8).Value

            .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2) = _
               Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 9).Value

            rng8.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3)

          End With
        End If

        If .Cells(i, 6) = "Mfg Raw PE" Then
          With Worksheets("ABCX Mfg Raw PE")

            .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = _
               Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 1).Value

            .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1) = _
               Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 8).Value

            .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2) = _
               Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 9).Value

            rng9.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3)

          End With
        End If

        If .Cells(i, 6) = "Mfg FG PVC" Then
          With Worksheets("ABCX Mfg FG PVC")

            .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = _
               Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 1).Value

            .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1) = _
               Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 8).Value

            .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2) = _
               Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 9).Value

            rng10.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3)

          End With
        End If


                If .Cells(i, 6) = "Mfg Raw PVC" Then
          With Worksheets("ABCX Mfg Raw PVC")

            .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = _
               Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 1).Value

            .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1) = _
               Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 8).Value

            .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2) = _
               Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 9).Value

            rng11.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3)

          End With
        End If

               If .Cells(i, 6) = "Mfg Sub-Assy PVC" Then
          With Worksheets("ABCX Mfg Sub-Assy PVC")

            .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = _
               Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 1).Value

            .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1) = _
               Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 8).Value

            .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2) = _
               Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 9).Value

            rng12.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3)

          End With
        End If

       Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Sounds like you might be interested in posting this question on [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead. A place that's dedicated to seeking peer review of code that allready works.

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Maybe Like this:**

You can make use of `Select Case` and Get rid of Extra Range Definitions as they are same for all the sheets.

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()

Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long

With Worksheets("Data")

LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row


For i = 2 To LastRow

    Select Case .Cells(i, 6)

    Case "Mfg FG"
        Call act(Worksheets("ABCX Mfg FG"), i)
    Case "Mfg RAW"
        Call act(Worksheets("ABCX Mfg RAW"), i)
    Case "Mfg Sub-Assy"
        Call act(Worksheets("ABCX Mfg Sub-Assy"), i)
    Case "Resale"
        Call act(Worksheets("ABCX Resale"), i)
    Case "Conv Resale"
        Call act(Worksheets("ABCX Conv Resale"), i)
    Case "Mfg FG PE"
        Call act(Worksheets("ABCX Mfg FG PE"), i)
    Case "Mfg Sub-Assy PE"
        Call act(Worksheets("ABCX Mfg Sub-Assy PE"), i)
    Case "Acrylics"
        Call act(Worksheets("ABCX Acrylics"), i)
    Case "Mfg Raw PE"
        Call act(Worksheets("ABCX Mfg Raw PE"), i)
    Case "Mfg FG PVC"
        Call act(Worksheets("ABCX Mfg FG PVC"), i)
    Case "Mfg Raw PVC"
        Call act(Worksheets("ABCX Mfg Raw PVC"), i)
    Case "Mfg Sub-Assy PVC"
        Call act(Worksheets("ABCX Mfg Sub-Assy PVC"), i)
    End Select
    Next i

End With

End Sub


Sub act(wks As Worksheet, j As Long)

    With wks

      .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = _
         Worksheets("Data").Cells(j, 1).Value

      .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1) = _
         Worksheets("Data").Cells(j, 8).Value

      .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2) = _
         Worksheets("Data").Cells(j, 9).Value

      .Range("A13:C1370").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3)

    End With

End Sub
```